# How to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis via JConsole?

Tags: activemq-artemis, jconsole

I am trying to connect via JConsole to ActiveMQ Artemis. However, it doesn't seem to work.

- JDK version: 1.8.0
- ActiveMQ Artemis version: 2.6.2

I have tried the following URLs both with and without user/password (admin/admin).:

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
```

and

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:1099/jmxrmi
```

My broker is running locally. I just unzipped it and created an instance. Here is my `management.xml`:

```xml
<management-context xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema">
  <connector connector-port="1099"/>
   <authorisation>
      <whitelist>
         <entry domain="hawtio"/>
      </whitelist>
      <default-access>
         <access method="list*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="get*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="is*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="set*" roles="amq"/>
         <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
      </default-access>
      <role-access>
         <match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis">
            <access method="list*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="get*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="is*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="set*" roles="amq"/>
            <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
         </match>
         <!--example of how to configure a specific object-->
         <!--<match domain="org.apache.activemq.artemis" key="subcomponent=queues">
            <access method="list*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
            <access method="get*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
            <access method="is*" roles="view,update,amq"/>
            <access method="set*" roles="update,amq"/>
            <access method="*" roles="amq"/>
         </match>-->
      </role-access>
   </authorisation>
</management-context>
```

I have tried the following:

1. Uncommented `<connector connector-port="1099"/>` in `management.xml` file
2. Uncommented in `artemis-service.xml`:

   ```xml
   <!-- uncomment this if you want to connect jconsole to connect -->
   <argument>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote</argument>
   <argument>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099</argument>
   <argument>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false</argument>
   <argument>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false</argument>
   ```
3. Add in `artemis-service.xml`:

   ```xml
   <argument>-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099</argument>
   ```

Comment: Hello,
And thank you for the answers.
I have added the details in the question.
Thanks

Comment: Did my answer address your question?

Answer (score 1):

I just got this working in ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.2 by doing the following:

1. Download and unzip ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.2 to `<ACTIVEMQ_HOME>`
2. Open a terminal and run `cd <ACTIVEMQ_HOME>/bin`
3. Create a new broker instance using `./artemis create ~/testJMX --user myUser --pass myPass --require-login`
4. Uncomment `<connector connector-port="1099"/>` in `etc/management.xml`.
5. Start the broker using `./artemis run`
6. Start JConsole using the `jconsole` command.
7. Point JConsole to `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi` using `myUser` & `myPass` for the username & password respectively.
8. Observe that JConsole connects properly and all MBeans are accessible.

I used JDK 1.8 on Linux. I don't have a Windows box I can test with.

It is **also possible** to get this working by changing steps #4 & #7 slightly:

1. Download and unzip ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.2 to `<ACTIVEMQ_HOME>`
2. Open a terminal and run `cd <ACTIVEMQ_HOME>/bin`
3. Create a new broker instance using `./artemis create ~/testJMX --user myUser --pass myPass --require-login`
4. Remove all of the contents of the `management-context` element in `etc/management.xml` so that you're left *only* with this:

   ```xml
   <management-context xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema" />
   ```
5. Start the broker using `./artemis run`
6. Start JConsole using the `jconsole` command.
7. Point JConsole to the local ActiveMQ Artemis *process*.
8. Observe that JConsole connects properly and all MBeans are accessible.

In general, I recommend you move to the [latest version](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/). ActiveMQ Artemis 2.6.2 was released almost 3 years ago now. Since 2.6.2 was released the JMX properties have been removed from `artemis-service.xml` as they are no longer applicable. See [ARTEMIS-2112](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2112) for more details.

Comment: Hello,
Thank you for the details of the actions taken.
I tested both procedures, I can't connect via jconsole.
I took the last version of Artemis, same problem.

I think I will make a Virtual Box with Windows, a jdk and Artemis and redo the tests.

Sincerely

Comment: Do you get any error message or anything like that? What *exactly* isn't working?

Comment: Hello,

It's better but not yet at the top.
I connect well in Jconsole.
I used directly the "Local Process" (org.apache.activemq.artemis.boot.Artemis run) and it works perfectly.

Now another problem when I want to run org.apache.activemq.artemis -> operations -> listqueues.
 I get an error 

Problem invoking listQueues: Java.lang.securityException: insufficent roles/credentials for operation

Sincerely

Comment: Did you complete step #4 from the second set of instructions? It indicates that you need to remove all of the contents of the `management-context` element in `etc/management.xml` so that you're left only with `<management-context xmlns="http://activemq.org/schema" />`. That's the only way to allow proper access when connecting to the broker as a local process with JConsole.